# Find a basis for $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$W=\{a,2a,a+2b,b+c|\text{ }a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_7\}$$

So far a visible basis is $a(1,2,1,0)+b(0,0,2,1)+c(0,0,0,1)$

So far the basis is $\{(1,2,1,0),(0,0,2,1),(0,0,0,1)\}$

But to be a basis for $W$, since $W$ is dimension $4$, should the basis have $4$ vectors?

So would I set up a matrix that has my current 3 basis vectors, and then the additional for $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ standard basis vectors, and get a basis from that?

Comment: Why is the dimension of $W$ four? I can't see that.

Comment: Do you mean that $W=\{(a,2a,a+2b,b+c)|\text{ }a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_7\}$?

Comment: no . of basis elements determines the dimension..not the no. of commas in the the defined set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that$$W=\{(a,2a,a+2b,b+c)|\text{ }a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_7\}$$

Obviously, $$\{(1,2,1,0),(0,0,2,1),(0,0,0,1)\}$$

is a spanning set for $W$.

Solving $\alpha (1,2,1,0)+\beta(0,0,2,1)+\gamma(0,0,0,1)=(0,0,0,0)$
gives that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$.

Therefore, the set is linearly independent too and it is indeed a basis for $W$. Therefore, by definition, the dimension of a space is the number of vectors in a basis, we see that $\dim{W}=3$ and what you have is indeed a basis for $W$.

Please do not confuse the dimension of the space that $W$ lives in it with the dimension of $W$ itself. A vector (sub-)space can always be embedded in spaces of higher dimensions, but that doesn't change the dimension of it.